# Prevent background from scrolling when a modal is open (NOT BOOTSTRAP)

Tags: css, scroll, modal-dialog

I have created my own modals from scratch and i want to prevent scrolling in the background when a modal is open, all i can find online is stuff about bootstrap which isn't helpful to me because my code doesn't automatically call 'modal-open' so

`body.modal-open{
overflow:hidden; 
}`

Doesn't work for me.

```
    <div id="wrapper3">
    <a class="button" href="#openModal-4">
    <img  class="image"src="img/Animation.png">
            <p class="text">Animation</p>

        </a>
        </div>
        <div id="openModal-4" class="modalbg">
          <div class="dialog">
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <div class="popout">
                        <h1>2D Animation Project</h1>
                        <div>
                        <h2>Project Brief</h2>

                        <a class="modalfullimg"><img src="img/Design/moodboard.png"></a>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Sketches</h2>
                        <a class="modalfullimg"><img src="img/Design/initialsketches.png"></a>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just modify the script you wrote to add a body class like 'modal-open' so you can apply the appropriate CSS? Seems like the easiest solution, if you're making it custom anyway.